# (C#) How to get the object which executed the method that executed the method that executed the currently executing method

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Forgive me for the absolutely abominable title of my question, but what I mean is: There is an object `A` that has a method `mA` that executes a method `mB` from an object `B`, then that method (`mB`) executes `mC` from the same object, finally, `mC` executes a virtual method `mD` from an object `C`, which I have overridden.

In code:

```cs
class A
{
    B b;
    void mA()
    {
        b.mB();
    }
}

class B
{
    public void mB()
    {
        mC();
    }

    D d;

    void mC()
    {
        d.mD();
    } 
}


class C
{
    public virtual void mD() { }
}

class D : C
{
    public override void mD()
    {
        A a = // Somehow get the A object that executed this
    }
}
```

Now that you know the very confusing situation, could you tell me how I would get object `A` from `mD`? (I do mean object, not class)

Before anyone tries to murder for crimes against good code, I just want to clarify that I'm making a mod, and cannot edit any of the classes (other than `D`). So this has to be solved some other way, I'm guessing through some reflection shenanigans, which I am okay with.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The only thing you can do is get the current stack trace, but that isn't very efficient. But you win a prize for best title of the day!

Comment: [StackTrace Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-6.0)